# Lombok @EqualsAndHashCode on a class which has a list

Tags: java, list, lombok

```java
@EqualsAndHashcode
class MyClass {
    String property1;
    List<NewClass> newClassList;
}
```

```java
@EqualsAndHashcode
class NewClass {
    String abc;
    String xyz;
}
```

If I compare two objects of `MyClass` (its annotated with `@EqualsAndHashcode`) for equality, will order of `newClassList` property be checked ?

Comment: Yes, because this is a list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I make sure that order is not compared.  Can I do any tweaking with EqualsAndHashcode or should I use a separate comparator for properties which are list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `@EqualsAndHashcode` it will propagate to use `newClassList.equals(..)` method which according to [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

> **Interface List**
>
> boolean equals(Object o) Compares the specified object with this list
> for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also
> a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of
> elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal
> if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) **In other words, two lists
> are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same
> order.** This definition ensures that the equals method works properly
> across different implementations of the List interface.

If you want a custom functionality where list does not check the order then you have to drop `@EqualsAndHashcode` and provide your own `equals` method based on what you want.

The functionality that you want would be in a simple way

```
(list1 != null && list2 != null && list1.size() == list2.size() && list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1) ) || (list1 == null && list2 == null)
```

This would lead us to the following equals method

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        NewClass newClass = (NewClass) o;
        return Objects.equals(property1, newClass.property1) &&
                ((newClassList != null && newClass.newClassList != null && newClassList.size() == newClass.newClassList.size() && newClassList.containsAll(newClass.newClassList) && newClass.newClassList.containsAll(newClassList) ) || (newClassList == null && list2 == null));
               
    }
```

Don't forget also to manually override `hashcode` method as well.